# PHP partially same namespace conflict

Tags: php, namespaces

I have a few PHP classes which are defined like this:

**module1Model.php**

```
namespace App\Modules\module1\models;

class module1Model
{
    //... methods etc.
}
```

**module2Model.php**

```
namespace App\Modules\module2\models;

class module2Model
{
    //... methods etc.
}
```

In some other class i want to use those namespaces. So i placed the following lines at the top of my page:

**someClass.php**

```
namespace App\Modules\someClass\controllers;

use App\Modules\module1\models; // Works
use App\Modules\module2\models; // Fails

use Core\Logger\TextLogger; // Works

class somceClass
{
    //... methods etc.
}
```

So in `someClass` i'm trying to `use` both `module1` and `module2` models. Which are technically not in the same namespace. Just partially. But why is it giving me an error about it then..??

And what would be a good way to solve this problem? I know i can add this to the second line:

```
use App\Modules\module2\models as module2; // Now works
```

But i don't really like to do it that way, since i didn't do it like that in all my other classes (using the `as` keyword). That feels so inconsistent.

Is there any other way to make this work..? Or am i really forced to use the `as` keyword in all my `use` declarations...? :-(

Comment: Nope. The whole purpose of namespaces is to distinguis classes with the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to use the model classes, not their whole namespace. If so, then the following just works:

```
use App\Modules\module1\models\module1Model;
use App\Modules\module2\models\module2Model;
```

Example:

```
namespace App\Modules\module1\models {
    class module1Model
    {
        //... methods etc.
    }
}

namespace App\Modules\module2\models {
    class module2Model
    {
        //... methods etc.
    }
}
namespace App\Modules\someClass\controllers {

use App\Modules\module1\models\module1Model;
use App\Modules\module2\models\module2Model;

use Core\Logger\TextLogger;

    class somceClass
    {
        //... methods etc.
    }
}
```